# How do I write a std::codecvt facet?

Tags: c++, windows, codecvt

How do I write a std::codecvt facet? I'd like to write ones that go from UTF-16 to UTF-8, which go from UTF-16 to the systems current code page (windows, so CP_ACP), and to the system's OEM codepage (windows, so CP_OEM).

Cross-platform is preferred, but MSVC on Windows is fine too. Are there any kinds of tutorials or anything of that nature on how to correctly use this class?

Comment: You might take a look at [the example in the libstdc++ manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/codecvt.html).

Comment: For locales and facets the only book I know that goes into any detail is http://www.angelikalanger.com/iostreams.html but it's only got  a few pages on codecvt specifically.

Comment: I can't believe that nobody seems to know squat about this class in the Standard library -- particularly given how potentially useful it can be...

Comment: 2James: that example is awkward. Conversion direction can't be stored in locale that way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've written one based on iconv. It can be used on windows or on any POSIX OS.
(You will need to link with iconv obviously).

[Enjoy](https://sourceforge.net/p/fakedetector/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/fakebase/src/codecvt_iconv.h)

The answer for the "how to" question is to follow  [the codecvt reference](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/codecvt.html). I was not able to find any better instructions in the Internet two years ago.

Important notices

- theoretically there is no need for such work. [codecvt_byname](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/codecvt-byname.html) should be enough on any standard supporting platform. But in reality there are some compilers that don't support or badly support this class.
  There is also a difference in interfaces of codecvt_byname on different compilers.
- my working example is implemented with state template parameter of codecvt. Always use standard mbstate type there as this is the only way to use your codecvt with standard iostream classes.
- std::mbstate_t type can't be used as a pointer on 64bit platforms in a cross-platform way.
- stateless conversions work for short strings, but may fail if you try to convert a data chunk greater that streambuf internal buffer size (UTF is essentially stateful encoding)

Comment: +1 -- I was not aware that `codecvt_byname` existed, and it turns out my compiler actually supports such a thing correctly. (Who knew?) Not accepting this yet because it isn't a direct answer to the question but if/when the bounty expires you'll get the points anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with this std::codecvt is it's a solution looking for a problem.  Or rather, the problem it's trying to solve is unsolvable, so anybody trying to use it as a solution is going to be very disappointed.

If you don't know which character set your input or output is, then std::codecvt isn't ever going to be able to help you.  Conversely, if you *do* know which character sets you're using, then you can trivially convert between them with a single function call.  Wrapping that function call in a complicated mess of templates doesn't change those fundamentals.

...and that's why nobody uses std::codecvt.  I recommend you just do what everybody else does, and pretend it never happened.

Comment: I know exactly what codepage and such I'm using. I want to be able to specify which codepage to use to iostreams. And the only way to do that is with `std::codecvt`. Sure, I can convert a block of text between code pages without a problem, but there's no way to say, "format this integer to be 8 spaces wide, fill the blanks with zeros" without a big mess of `std::wstringstream` s. I'd rather just be able to make iostreams natively convert to the correct codepage given it already has a facility for doing so. -1 for not answering the question.

Comment: As for "Nobody uses `std::codecvt`", can you explain why conversion facets for Unicode are being added in C++0x, and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html ?

Comment: Probably in the hopes that people will *start* using std::codecvt once it's no longer useless.