# STL and UTF-8 file input/output. How to do it?

Tags: c++, stl, utf-8

I use `wchar_t` for internal strings and UTF-8 for storage in files. I need to use STL to input/output text to *screen* and also do it by using full Lithuanian charset.
It's all fine because I'm not forced to do the same for *files*, so the following example does the job just fine:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
    _setmode (_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wcout << L"AaĄąﬂ" << endl;
```

But I became curious and attempted to do the same with files with no success. Of course I could use formatted input/output, but that is... *discouraged*.

```
    FILE* fp;
    _wfopen_s (&fp, L"utf-8_out_test.txt", L"w");
    _setmode (_fileno (fp), _O_U8TEXT);
    _fwprintf_p (fp, L"AaĄą\nﬂ");
    fclose (fp);
    _wfopen_s (&fp, L"utf-8_in_test.txt", L"r");
    _setmode (_fileno (fp), _O_U8TEXT);
    wchar_t text[256];
    fseek (fp, NULL, SEEK_SET);
    fwscanf (fp, L"%s", text);
    wcout << text << endl;
    fwscanf (fp, L"%s", text);
    wcout << text << endl;
    fclose (fp);
```

This snippet works **perfectly** (although I am not sure how it handles malformed chars). So, is there any way to:

- get `FILE*` or integer file handle form a `std::basic_*fstream`?
- simulate `_setmode ()` on it?
- extend `std::basic_*fstream` so it handles UTF-8 I/O?

Yes, I am studying at an university and this is somewhat related to my assignments, but I am trying to figure this out for myself. It won't influence my grade or anything like that.

Comment: Googling "stl utf8" yields http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/utf8facet.aspx about midway on the first page.

Comment: @zneak Oh, my. I didn't expect a LMGTFY (let alone with my own keywords). Anyway, this is exactly what I was looking for, although I was hoping for something that would be possible to memorize. Silly me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use std::codecvt_facet template to perform the conversion.

You may use standard [std::codecvt_byname](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/codecvt-byname.html), or a non-standard codecvt_facet [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971386/how-do-i-write-a-stdcodecvt-facet/2987731#2987731).

```
#include <locale>
using namespace std;
typedef codecvt_facet<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t> Cvt;
locale utf8locale(locale(), new codecvt_byname<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t> ("en_US.UTF-8"));
wcout.pubimbue(utf8locale);
wcout << L"Hello, wide to multybyte world!" << endl;
```

Beware that on some platforms codecvt_byname can only emit conversion only for locales that are installed in the system.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after some testing I figured out that `FILE` is accepted for `_iobuf` (in the `w*fstream` constructor). So, the following code does what I need.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
//For writing
    FILE* fp;
    _wfopen_s (&fp, L"utf-8_out_test.txt", L"w");
    _setmode (_fileno (fp), _O_U8TEXT);
    wofstream fs (fp);
    fs << L"ąﬂ";
    fclose (fp);
//And reading
    FILE* fp;
    _wfopen_s (&fp, L"utf-8_in_test.txt", L"r");
    _setmode (_fileno (fp), _O_U8TEXT);
    wifstream fs (fp);
    wchar_t array[6];
    fs.getline (array, 5);
    wcout << array << endl;//For debug
    fclose (fp);
```

This sample reads and writes legit UTF-8 files (without BOM) in Windows compiled with Visual Studio 2k8.

Can someone give any comments about portability? Improvements?

Comment: Thank you verymuch :) This solved my mind buggling question:)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to do the conversion to UTF-8 yourself before trying to output. You might get some inspiration from this question: [UTF8 to/from wide char conversion in STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148403/utf8-to-from-wide-char-conversion-in-stl)

Comment: I know how to convert (I wrote a decoder), but I was wondering if there was a less troublesome way.

Comment: IMHO codecvt facet (once implemented) is a convenient way to perform conversions in STL. Why troublesome?

Comment: _Less troublesome_ would be if you could memorize it. Despite that, I agree that facet is convenient in most cases (until standards offer something internal).

Answer (score 0):

> get FILE* or integer file handle form a std::basic_*fstream?

[Answered elsewhere.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream)

Comment: Um, scratch that, FILE* fp; wofstream fs (fp); seems to work just fine!

Answer (score -3):

You can't make STL to directly work with UTF-8. The basic reason is that STL indirectly forbids multi-char characters. Each character has to be one char/wchar_t.

Microsoft actually breaks the standard with their UTF-16 encoding, so maybe you can get some inspiration there.

Comment: In first snippet if I omit _setmode wcout doesn't work. I thought it would be same with files too. And after executing second snippet I tested it, the output file was a legit UTF-8.

Comment: @transistor09 Yes, you can read and output UTF-8, but you can't store UTF-8 in any other way then raw data or encoded in UTF-32 (UTF-16 in Windows).

Comment: @Let_Me_Be That's what I want: keep wchar_t in RAM and store UTF-8 in HDD.

Comment: -1, simply untrue. `char` can have a multibyte encoding, and `std::string` doesn't change that. The Standard Library explicitly confirms it, in fact: There's no reason to have `std::codecvt::max_length` if it would be always be 1

Comment: @MSalters That specifies the number of external characters matching one internal! Not the other way around.

Comment: @transistor09 Check the UTF-8 facet mentioned in the comment to your question. That is the correct approach.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: The specialiazation `codecvt<char,char,mbstate_t>` is a no-op. In the specialization `codecvt<wchar_t,char,mbstate_t>`, the "internal" character is `wchar_t` and the "external" characters are chars, up to `char[codecvt<wchar_t,char,mbstate_t>::max_length]`

Comment: @MSalters I have no idea why you are arguing with me. What I saying is that you can't have an UTF-8 or UTF-16 std::string (std::basic_string) and not break the standard. The external encoding can be anything. I'm talking about the internal encoding.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Sorry, but that is just not true. I cannot prove the absence of such a rule, but if you think there's a rule in the standard you should be able to point to it. Should be in chapter 20 somewhere?

Comment: @MSalters It is indirectly forbidden. For example, the definition of null terminated wide character sequence defines the length as the number of elements before the NULL character. If you have a variable length encoding, then this is not true.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: A "null terminated wide character sequence" is not an STL or a `std::basic_string<charT>` concept. It's a basic C concept, carried over to C++. Besides, UTF-8 would be used for Multi-Byte encodings (`char[]`), not wide characters (`wchar_t[]`).

Comment: @MSalters `char` has even stricter limitations then `wchar_t`.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be : no it doesn't. The standard explicitly acknowledges multi-byte character sequences. The library agrees, there's no point in having mcslen unless it differs from strlen. Furthermore, that still is the C legacy. You _still_ haven't indicated how the STL (`std::basic_string`) would forbid it.

Comment: @MSalters Well, obviously yes you need `wcslen` in both cases, simply because it takes `const wchar_t*` and not `const char*`.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be :Sorry, mixup there. `mcslen` is not standard. But I found the even clearer example: `MB_CUR_MAX` is the maximum number of chars in a single multi-byte character. Eseentially, you state that the standard requires that `MB_CUR_MAX==1`. Why is it then even a #define ?!

Comment: @MSalters `MB_CUR_MAX` should be number of bytes per `wchar_t` not number of `wchar_t` per platform-character. At least that is how I understand the description.

Comment: A wide character is not a multibyte character, within the language of the standard. [defns.multibyte]: "a sequence of one or more bytes representing a member of the extended character set of either the source or the execution environment." [lib.locale.codecvt]: "The class codecvt<internT,externT,stateT> is for use when converting from one codeset to another, such as from wide characters to multibyte characters." Also, the number of bytes per `wchar_t` is `sizeof wchar_t`.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: `MB_CUR_MAX` has nothing to do with `wchar_t`.