# using wregex creates garbage output?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, c++11, wofstream

I created a simple program using regex to tokenize a file. For nonUnicode content it works fine. For a Unicode based content I made a wregex version but this version creates garbage output!

I am trying to output Unicode characters or strings on a console screen instead I stored them in a `map<wstring,int>` and a file of type wostream so that the values are intact and correct.
After running the application the file containing the extracted tokens, contain just garbage!!!

Whats wrong with this program and how can I fix it?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path="";    

    map<wstring, int> container;
    wifstream file("ftest.txt"); 
    wregex reg(_T("\\w+"));
    wstring s=_T("");
    while (file.good())
    {
        file>>s;
        for ( wsregex_iterator it (s.begin(), s.end(), reg),it_end; it != it_end; ++it)
        {
            container[(wstring)(*it)[0]]++ ;
        }

    }

    cout <<"\nDone..."<< endl;
    wofstream output("list.txt",ios::app);
    for (auto item : container)
    {
        //cout<<item.first<<" : "<<item.second<<endl;
        output<<item.first<<" : "<<item.second<<endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the content of `ftest.txt`:

```
بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم 
واشنگتن پست طی گزارشی اعلام کرد کنگره آمریکا برخلاف رویه سابق، ارسال مصوبه سالانه خود در زمینه تحریم های ایران به کاخ سفید را به تاخیر انداخت و به نظر می رسد انتخاب حسن روحانی به عنوان رئیس جمهوری جدید ایران علت این امر بوده است.
0 0 0 نظر
[-]     اندازه متن  [+]


به دنبال انتخاب حسن روحانی به عنوان رئیس جمهوری جدید ایران، کنگره آمریکا بر اساس برخی ملاحظات ارسال مصوبه سالانه خود در زمینه تحریم های ایران به کاخ سفید را به تاخیر انداخت.
```

And this is the garbage output inside `list.txt`

```
0 : 3
1 : 1
14 : 1
16 : 1
26 : 1
27 : 1
5 : 2
50 : 1
6 : 1
7 : 1
ط : 475
طھ : 12
طھط : 20
طھطµظ : 1
طھظ : 10
طھغ : 2
ط² : 6
ط²ط : 6
ط²ظ : 6
ط³ : 5
ط³ط : 12
ط³طھ : 8
ط³طھط : 4
ط³طھظ : 2
ط³ظ : 10
ط³غ : 1
طµ : 1
طµط : 1
طµظ : 6
ط¹ط : 1
ط¹ظ : 8
ظ : 291
ع : 54
غ : 95
ï : 1
```

Comment: Are you sure your textfile is UTF16? and not UTF8?

Comment: its UTF8! what should i do now?

Comment: Either you convert the file to UTF16 or you find another regex library which supports UTF8 strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4027456/938244)  Solved my problem.:) for a portable solution check this [link](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) out.

And this is the final code which works flawlessly :) :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fcntl.h> // for _wfopen_s
#include <io.h> //for _setmode


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path = "";    

    map<wstring, int> container;

     FILE* fp;
    _wfopen_s (&fp, L"ftest.txt", L"r");
    _setmode (_fileno (fp), _O_U8TEXT);

    wifstream file(fp);
    wregex reg(L"\\w+");

    wstring s = L"";

    while (file.good())
    {
        getline(file,s);    
        for ( wsregex_iterator it (s.begin(), s.end(), reg), it_end ; it != it_end ; ++it)
        {
            container[(wstring)(*it)[0]]++ ;
        }
    }

    cout <<"\nDone..."<< endl;

    fclose(fp);

    _wfopen_s (&fp, L"list.txt", L"w");
    _setmode (_fileno (fp), _O_U8TEXT);
    wofstream output(fp);

    for (auto item : container)
    {
        wcout<<item.first <<" : "<<item.second <<endl;
        //write output to list.txt
        output<<item.first <<" : "<<item.second <<endl;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert from the UTF8 encoding of the file to the UTF16 encoding that `std::wregex` uses.

With C++11 you can do it using [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16):

```
std::wifstream file("ftest.txt"); 
file.imbue(std::locale(file.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>());
// "file" will now read UTF8 and output UTF16.
```

Pre C++11 you can use [`boost::locale`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html) to convert:

e.g.

```
auto w_s = boost::locale::utf_to_utf<char>(s);
```

Comment: i get these errors:
Error 1 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'codecvt_utf8_utf16
'
Error 2 error C2665: 'std::locale::locale' : none of the 9 overloads could convert all the argument types

3 IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "std::locale::locale" matches the argument list
 argument types are: (std::locale, <error-type>)
           
4 IntelliSense: expected a type specifier

5 IntelliSense: type name is not allowed

6 IntelliSense: expected an expression

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012 SP3