# The non-English character ó in XML

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

I've a huge XML file, which has a list of software names and it's versions.  One of it is having a non-English character **ó** as in the below snippet.
If i open the XML file with the browser it doesn't display anything. But if i just remove this non-English character **ó** , the entire XML is displayed.

```
<Item Software="SDK de comprobación de Visual Studio 2012 - esn" Version= "12.0.30501" />
```

This clearly means that the non-english character ó is causing this to happen.

This is how my XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Softwares>
<Item Software="SDK de comprobación de Visual Studio 2012 - esn" Version= "12.0.30501" />
<Item Software="Notepad++" Version= "72.0.45" />
<Item Software="MyApp" Version= "7.8.45" />
..................................
</Softwares>
```

Does it have to do something with the encoding? I get the same result
 even with no encoding mentioned which i think defaults to utf-8 again. Also i tried giving UTF-16 as format which also doesn't work.
I'm pretty new to XML.

Comment: Are you sure your file is encoded in UTF-8?  It's valid XML otherwise.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> is the exact line i used in the begining of XML file. Is it correct.

Comment: That line doesn't control the encoding, it only declares it. You have to save the file in that encoding as well.

Comment: how can i save XML file as utf8 programatically in C++ using std::fstream ?.

Comment: That is another question, but it has been asked many times on SO.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018384/stl-and-utf-8-file-input-output-how-to-do-it is one.

Comment: XML has no concept of English. And, ó is occasionally [used in English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_terms_spelled_with_%C3%93). It's a symptom of saying the file is UTF-8 when it's not. So, you are lucky to a nice indicator of that. One way of getting it right is to use an XML library that will match the declared encoding to the file encoding upon save.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the XML you've posted, including the 
Unicode character, LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE, ó.